# Alinhar textos com divs diferentes na mesma linha

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, estou com um problema, criei uma popup apenas para newsletter, porém ao passar ela para o html, com css, precisei usar 2 divs (tentei usar todas as formas possiveis, fonts, p, span) diferentes para mudar a cor e sombra do texto. Não sei se vão conseguir entender mas preciso alinhar 2 divs na mesma linha. Sem querer, segue como está: [image: como está] agora segue como deveria estar: [image: como deveria]

Peço que levem em conta apenas o título "Promoções exclusivas direto no seu email" o resto irei passar assim que solucionar esse problema.

Obrigado a todos que leram e tenham um ótimo dia.

Comment: Votando para fechar por ter sido [um erro de digitação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117246/4808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.text p{
  font-size 20px;
  color: #000;
}
.text p i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ff0;
}
.text{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Promoções exclusivas direto no seu <i>email</i></p>
  </div>
```

Tenta colocar algoo assim para o texto, coloca dentro de alguma tag e aplica o css na tag. Irá funcionar, trabalhe com os floats!

Comment: Funcionou certinho e deixou mais organizado kk obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de você já ter se auto respondido, acho interessante deixar uma resposta para quem sabe lhe tirar uma duvida que restou, ou ajudar a esclarecer melhor.

O seu problema estava ocorrendo pois ambos os elementos estavam com a propriedade `display: block`, e quando se assume essa propriedade não é possível alinhar dois elementos lado a lado. Sendo assim, bastava você colocar esta propriedade como `display:inline-block` que o problema estaria resolvido.

**Obs:** É importante lembrar que existem elementos que já são criados com a propriedade `display:block` e outros não. A seguir estão dois links para você dar uma olhada...

- https://jsfiddle.net/j1agndmc/2/
- http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/display.html

Comment: Obrigado pela complementação e pela ajuda, agradeço

Comment: De nada cara, estamos aqui para isso!

Answer (score -1):

Sempre que eu faço uma pergunta por aqui, o problema se soluciona sozinho haha, bom pra quem tem o mesmo problema que eu e já tentou muitas formas em css e nenhuma dava certo, é bem improvável que alguém vai ser tão "lesado" como eu de esquecer que adicionou tag  no próprio HTML dando conflito e bugando tudo, não sei se display: block faz isso, porém deu esse problema e só foi retirar que o problema foi solucionado.

Obrigado a todos !!!